# Conflict between Bootstrap tabbable and popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am trying to use Twitter Bootstrap tabbable and Bootstrap popovers in a same page. I am having difficulties resoling the problem of popovers that can't appear beyond tab's limits (problem is when the popover appears next to a border, it's half-hidden).

I am not an expert in JQuery, but as far as I understand, the problem comes from tabs being created in "iframes", and popovers can't be displayed out of its "iframe".

Is there any way I could resolve this problem? (= displaying correctly the popover even when close to tab's border ?)

Thanks a lot!

Below is a sample code showing my problem (ready to copy/paste in a .html http://jsfiddle.net/7PU2D/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="span2">
    Left column
</div>
<div class="span6">
    <div class="tabbable">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">tab1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">tab3</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active">tab1 text
                <div class="well">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" rel="popover" style="position: relative;" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right? " data-original-title="A Title">hover for popover</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane">tab2 text</div>
            <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane">tab3 taxt</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $('a[rel=popover]').popover({
      trigger: 'hover',
      placement: 'in bottom',
      animate: true,
      delay: 500,
});
});  
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tab content div has the css property `overflow` set to `auto` (by Bootstrap). This means that when the size of the content exceeds the size of the div, the browser adds a scrollbar and clips the content. You can overwrite the property to its default (`visible`) in one of your own css files, or just by using inline styles like this:

```
<div class="tab-content" style="overflow: visible;">
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/grc4/BXmC3/

Comment: if you resize, part of the message is hidden when the .container margin is low. I would rather use `placement: 'in right',` instead of `placement: 'in bottom',` to avoid that.

Comment: grc: Thanks a lot, that is exactly what I was looking for !

baptme: I am actually using (in the real app) a content that can be anywhere in the tab-content, thus making it hard to avoid the problem by setting the popover in a specific direction (ex: if I set "in right", there will be a problem when the text with popover will be close to the right border).

Answer (score 4):

Use the "container" option.  This way you can append the popover/tip to the body element where it will not get chopped off by the tabs pane overflow:hidden...example:

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $('a[rel=popover]').popover({
   trigger: 'hover',
   placement: 'in bottom',
   animate: true,
   delay: 500,
   container: 'body'
   });
});  
</script>
```

or:

```
 <a rel="popover" data-container="body">Pop Me Open</a>
```

Your tooltip will still be placed correctly next to your link, but since its now attached to the body tag, its not going to be "half-hidden" by the tab pane.

see the docs for tooltip/popover on the bootstrap site...

2.3.2:

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#popovers

or 3.0

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Answer (score -1):

Instead of $ use jQuery It may resolve your conflicts. I think you have to increase the height of the tab content like this

```
.tab-content
{
    height:400px;
}
```

Comment: muthu: like I said to baptme, I can't avoid the problem this way, since the tab-content is supposed to be filled in the real app. Thanks anyway for your contribution.